# How to loop over images array and render them in a component for React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, loops

I have a list of 5 images in my react app which I would like to cycle through in an **infinite loop**. I basically want to animate these 5 frames so that a light bar looks like a light that is constantly moving.

[image]

So the dot which shifts in each image will look as though it is moving.

I am currently importing each image and rendering it in react-bootstraps `Image` component. I know my approach is probably off below. How would I go about doing this accurately?

**My attempts**

```
//images
import bar1 from "../assets/bar1.png";
import bar2 from "../assets/bar2.png";
import bar3 from "../assets/bar3.png";
import bar4 from "../assets/bar4.png";
import bar5 from "../assets/bar5.png";

//my state
  state = {
    bars:[bar1,bar2,bar3,bar4,bar5]
  };

//function to cycle (this needs to run infinitely)
 cycleBars =()=> {
    let finalBar = this.state.bars0]; 
    //return this.state.bars[0];
    this.state.bars.map(e=>{
      finalBar = e;
    })
    return finalBar;
  }


//return from my component

<Image src={this.cycleBars()} />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will have gone with *CSS animation*. Here is the solution in **React**:

```
 state = {
    bars:[bar1,bar2,bar3,bar4,bar5],
    activeImageIndex: 0
 };

 componentDidMount(){
   setInterval(()=>{
     let newActiveIndex = this.state.activeImageIndex===4 ? 0 : this.state.activeImageIndex+1     
     this.setState({
        activeImageIndex: newActiveIndex
     })
   }, 1000);


 }

 <Image src={this.state.bars[activeImageIndex]} />
```

Comment: this is how you do it in the "react" way

Comment: css would have been better but I wanted a react way for this. Worked like a charm, thanks guys!

Comment: btw does looping through an image like this have any negative effects as far as bloating a website? Was curious if you knew.

Comment: i would suggest to create a gif and, let it roll its way

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way might be to do this with CSS:

```css
.lightbox {
  border: solid 3px black;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 24px;
  align-items: center;
}

.light {
  border: solid 3px black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  animation: blink 5s linear infinite;
}

.light:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s
}

.light:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s
}

.light:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 3s
}

.light:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 4s
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    background-color: orangered;
  }
  19% {
    background-color: orangered;
  }
  20% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

.lightbox::before,
.lightbox::after {
  content: "";
  border: solid 1.5px black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.lightbox::before {
  left: -24px;
}

.lightbox::after {
  right: -24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lightbox">
  <div class="light"></div>
  <div class="light"></div>
  <div class="light"></div>
  <div class="light"></div>
  <div class="light"></div>
</div>
```