# How to work around a slowdown from looping through images in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, loops, resources

I'm currently looping through a list of images with the purpose of animating the movement of a light on a bar. Unfortunately I am not using CSS because it seems to me for my setup this looping would probably be the best way but it seems to eat a lot of resources so I am wondering if there is a way around this or if I simply have to change everything. Below is the code I am using:

Help on the code came from here:

[How to loop over images array and render them in a component for React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59117736/how-to-loop-over-images-array-and-render-them-in-a-component-for-react)

[image]

**Code**

```
    state = {
    bars:[bar1,bar2,bar3,bar4,bar5],
    activeImageIndex: 0
 };

 componentDidMount(){
   setInterval(()=>{
     let newActiveIndex = this.state.activeImageIndex===4 ? 0 : this.state.activeImageIndex+1     
     this.setState({
        activeImageIndex: newActiveIndex
     })
   }, 1000);


 }

 <Image src={this.state.bars[activeImageIndex]} />
```

The code functions well for a bit then the app slows down as more resources seem to be taken. Checking the network tool I can see resources growing (files are named differently in my app):

[image]

Is there a better way to approach this? Or perhaps a way to free resources after each call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the guy who gave the react answer :)

Everything with a setInterval overtime will slow down, especially if you modify dom every 1second using javascript, **especially when they are images**.

Every time the setInterval is called the browser need's to repaint the container with the next image, this paint can cost a lot of ms, but if it costs more than 16ms(60fps), frame is dropped and your application will start to become laggy.

That's why the animation king is: **CSS**

```css
.lightbox {
  border: solid 3px black;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 24px;
  align-items: center;
}

.light {
  border: solid 3px black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  animation: blink 5s linear infinite;
}

.light:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s
}

.light:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s
}

.light:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 3s
}

.light:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 4s
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    background-color: orangered;
  }
  19% {
    background-color: orangered;
  }
  20% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

.lightbox::before,
.lightbox::after {
  content: "";
  border: solid 1.5px black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.li
```

```html
<div class="lightbox">
  <div class="light"></div>
  <div class="light"></div>
  <div class="light"></div>
  <div class="light"></div>
  <div class="light"></div>
</div>
```

This snippet over time it won't lag and most importantly it ***won't block the thread***.